# What is wear leveling in SD cards? How I can check my sd card has wear leveling or not?

Tags: microcontroller, sd

I searched on internet. Still I'm not clear about wear leveling can somebody explain this concept?

Comment: The NAND Flash technology is not reliable, bits sometimes become unusable after several write. So there is a small controller that levels the wear-makes new data being written in places where nothing has been written before. So there is no situation when after several files deleted and written one area gets more weared then the others and hence more vulnerable. Your flash, if made in recent ten years, has wear leveling. Look up in datasheet.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I doubt if low-price Chinese knockoffs do wear-leveling -- I was told a couple years ago that it cost 30¢ to add it.  That may have changed though.  In any case, I would stick with only the name brands -- Kingston, SanDisk etc.

Comment: I don't know. I thought, it's done as part of same silicone process, 30 cents seems way too much

Comment: @GregoryKornblum that may represent the OEM cost of the feature (as was quoted to us), not the actual cost of manufacture.

Comment: I can't comment :) but for me it's very surprising. I would look for other vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from SanDisk's website:

> Wear Leveling
>
> Wear Leveling ensures even distribution of erase operations on all
>   blocks within the NAND flash. That is, each block within the NAND
>   flash is erased and written approximately the same number of times as
>   every other block within the drive.
>
> To understand Wear Leveling, one needs to understand the different
>   addressing schemes in a system. The operating system (OS) uses Logical
>   Block Addressing (LBA) to read and write a block of data from the
>   drive; the flash controller uses physical addresses on the flash to
>   read and write data.
>
> Wear Leveling is based upon two mechanisms:
>
> - The controller has the ability to map an LBA address to different    physical locations on the flash. The controller uses a mapping table
>     to keep track of the relationship between the logical block and the
>     physical address
> - The presence of spare blocks on the flash for replacement of blocks    that contain invalid data
>
> Updated or new data is written to an available free block. The block
>   that contains old data is erased in the background and then marked as
>   a free block. This block rotating technique ensures even wear of
>   memory blocks across the flash device. The Wear Leveling process is
>   transparent to the operating system.

Comment: Does it means that wear leveling need to be supported on controller, or is it that it is already supported in the sd card itself. opening sandisk datasheet, it seems that the device itself supports wear leveling, not the controller https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/04db416b291011446889dbd6129e2644.pdf